# nginx serve welcome page for domain and my site for ip

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have following problem.

I have recently attached domain to my IP. There was a django application deployed with nginx and uwsgi.

The problem is that when I open `mydomain.ru` - I get nginx welcome page.

When I open my ip in browser - I get my site as it is.

I tried to run django application with `runserver` - it works both for domain and for ip. So the problem is with nginx

Here is nginx.conf:

```
upstream django {
server unix:///home/django/venv/mysite/onelove.sock fail_timeout=1000; 
}

server {
listen      80;
server_name     **.**.**.** #my ip
charset     utf-8;
proxy_read_timeout 1000;
proxy_send_timeout 1000;

client_max_body_size 75M;
location /media  {
    alias /home/django/venv/mysite/vkmodule/media;  
}


location /static {
    alias /home/django/venv/mysite/vkmodule/static;  

}
location /static/admin {
  alias /home/django/venv/mysite/admin/static; 
}
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /home/django/venv/mysite/uwsgi_params; 
    uwsgi_read_timeout 18000;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 18000;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've blanked out the `server_name` field, but from the comment it seems that you have your IP address there, rather than the actual name. If you want nginx to respond to the domain name, you need to put it in `server_name`.